# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException, (need to add null to the arrayList), 2-dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

This problem has been faced a lot of time, I know, I came across those questions but couldnt understand my issue. This is a part of my code given below,

```
public ArrayList<Slice> network_slices;
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nfs_slices= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
public int index;

private class TabSelect implements ChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JTabbedPane source = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
            if (source.getSelectedComponent() != null) {
                index = source.getSelectedIndex();
            }
        }
    }

private int count = 0;
    private class AddNetworkFuncitons implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String buttonselected = (String) e.getActionCommand();
            JButton button = new JButton(buttonselected);
            network_slices.get(index).add(button).setVisible(true);
            int c =nf_list.indexOf(buttonselected);
            System.out.println(index);
            System.out.println(c);

            nfs_slices.get(index).set(c,nf_list.get(c));
            System.out.println(nfs_slices);
//          System.out.println(nfs_slices.get(index));
            count ++;
        }
    }
```

Whenever the action gets performed, it should add `buttonselected` string to the arraylist corresponding the `index` list (as there is 2-dimensional ArrayList). The index is being changed by changeListener anytime.

Where `nf_list` is a ArrayList of String containing 4 element right now.
But it throws the exception.
I initialized `network_slices` inside the Constructor, `network_slices = new ArrayList<Slice>();`

Comment: where is `nf_list` declared and where u had initialized `network_slices` ? post the complete code and exception trace.

Comment: I edited in the question.

Comment: You are storing the index in state. When you set your network_slices to a new ArrayList, then its new size is zero. So, without any elements inside it, any call to get(index) will fail. You need to add a check that ensures that your network_slices ArrayList is not empty.

Comment: Are you talking about nfs_slices, because when network_slices call to get(index). it works finde, I think nfs_slices cant call get (index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't guarantee that network_slices indeed contains an object in the accessed index, therefore you have a null pointer exception.

At least check that it is not null before making any operations on it...

Comment: the network_slices is not empty, it has now 4 JPanel inside, I am giving this below,

[network.slicing.Slice[,0,0,0x0,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=550,height=600]]]

[network.slicing.Slice[,2,25,550x634,....], 
[network.slicing.Slice[,0,0,0x0,...]]]
and so on,

Comment: But you do have a null pointer exception... Debug and check the index value and the array contents in real time...

Comment: index value of nfs_slices or network_slices ? network_slices is a empty arraylist, and nfs_slices is 2-d arralylist.

Comment: You can't call get(index) on an empty ArrayList. It's going to fail. Ensure your ArrayList has an element at that index first. You need to check the size of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ManoDestra, I think I came up with the solution. I will post as answer,

Answer (score 0):

I have added null list to the 2d array, in each row. I added it in the constructor so that before using it, it wont be empty, and I can call get(index),

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        nfs_slices.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        for(int j=0; j<nf_number; j++)
            nfs_slices.get(i).add(null);
    }
```

Now it can call get(index) and put the element in the specific place.
Thanks guys for helping me.